# Angular 6 - Rxjs 6 - Type Observable<Object> is not assignable to type Observable<Item>

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

After updated my Angular project from version 5 to 6 I got this error:

> Type Observable'<'Object> is not assignable to type Observable'<'Todo>.

in my todo.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { environment } from '../../../environments/environment';
import { Todo } from '../../../models/Todo';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';

@Injectable()
export class TodoService {

  todos: Todo[];

  constructor( private httpClient: HttpClient ) { }

  loadTodos(): Observable<Todo[]> {
    return this.httpClient.get<Todo[]>(`${environment.api}${environment.path}`).pipe(
      catchError((error: any) => Observable.throw(error))
    );
  }

  addTodo(todo: Todo): Observable<Todo> {
    return this.httpClient.post(`${environment.api}${environment.path}`, JSON.stringify(todo)).pipe(
      catchError((error: any) => Observable.throw(error))
    );
  }

  editTodo(todo: Todo): Observable<Todo> {
    return this.httpClient.put(`${environment.api}${environment.path}/${todo.id}`, JSON.stringify(todo)).pipe(
      catchError((error: any) => Observable.throw(error))
    );
  }

  deleteTodo(todo: Todo): Observable<Todo> {
    return this.httpClient.delete(`${environment.api}${environment.path}/${todo.id}`).pipe(
      catchError((error: any) => Observable.throw(error))
    );
  }
}
```

The error points to addTodo, editTodo, and deleteTodo methods, loadTodo has no issues since it assigns Observable'<'Object> type to Observable'<'Array> type.
I used [this link](https://auth0.com/blog/whats-new-in-rxjs-6/) to change the way rxjs elements are imported, but without success. Any help ?

Comment: How about trying `post<Todo[]>`?

Comment: post<Todo[]> means that we post an array, can you please explain more ?

Comment: Using `post<Todo[]>` would mean the post request would return a `Todo` array. What you post in the body wouldn't matter or change.

Comment: Try casting the post, put and delete method with <Todo>. E.g: http.post<Todo>()

Comment: Like what you did with your get method, do the same for everything else but with Todo instead of Todo[]

Comment: @ChauTran Thank you, it worked fine.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

httpClient methods are generic, you have to type the response, for example:

```
    addTodo(todo: Todo): Observable<Todo> {
        return this.httpClient.post(`${environment.api}${environment.path}`, JSON.stringify(todo)).pipe(
      catchError((error: any) => Observable.throw(error))
    );
  }
```

has to be used like this:

```
    addTodo(todo: Todo): Observable<Todo> {
    return this.httpClient.post<Todo>(`${environment.api}${environment.path}`, JSON.stringify(todo)).pipe(
      catchError((error: any) => Observable.throw(error))
    );
  }
```

Comment: Yes as answered by @ChauTran above 2 hours earlier, but how HttpClient could be generic with Angular 6 and not with Angular 5, the service was working without issues in Angular 5.

Comment: Huh, I miss "...post<Todo>". Thanks!